# Incompatible Class Change Error: jaxrs-0.7 vs mail-1.0.1

Tags: java, grails, jax-rs, grails-plugin

I have a dependency resolution issue with another plugin, which is causing the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$RenderEnvironment.init(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:125)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$RenderEnvironment.with(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:158)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer.render(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:47)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.doRender(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:235)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.html(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:253)
```

The way to recreate the error:
Install jaxrs 0.7 plugin and its dependencies in build config: spock 0.7 and org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.2.RELEASE

When I do run-app, since everything is loaded directly from resources, there is no error. However, doing a run-war, as dependencies are resolved I get the the above error.

The mail plugin depends on org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.0.RELEASE which gets kicked out. So, probably that is the reason.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue? I don't necessarily want to recompile the plugin separately as it becomes hard to maintain. I already tried a lot of combination in buildconfig for exclusion, but doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your BuildConfig?

Comment: @SérgioMichels The relevant parts of the build config for jaxrs-0.7 to work:                               compile('org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.2.RELEASE'){
                excludes "mail"
         }

}

 plugins {
  build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"


        test(":spock:0.6") {

        }

    }